# terminal formatting issue after vim

Tags: shell

I had ~3000 files in a directory with the name "build.xml", and when I did

```
find ./ -name build.xml|xargs vi
```

I then quit vi, and I see the formatting on the terminal got messed up. I cannot see any keyboard input, and when I press return, I see the newline characters get eaten up.

```
[Fri Jun 21 20:41:58:~ ] $ [Fri Jun 21 20:41:58:~ ] $ [Fri Jun 21 20:41:58:~ ] $ [Fri Jun 21 20:41:58:~ ] $ [Fri Jun 21 20:41:58:~ ] $ [Fri Jun 21 20:41:58:~ ] $ [Fri Jun 21 20:41:58:~ ] $ [Fri Jun 21 20:41:59:~ ] $ -bash: ks: command not found
                                                                                  [Fri Jun 21 20:45:08:~ ] $
```

What is happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try quitting the terminal?

Comment: no i did not quit the terminal, and i don't want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell could be doing something funny with I/O due to the `|` operator.

First of all, you can always reset your terminal by typing `reset`. But to avoid the issue, try using `$()` instead of piping to xargs. Like this:

```
vi $(find ./ -name build.xml)
```

Or

```
vi `find ./ -name build.xml`
```

Answer (score 3):

Vim probably did not reset the terminal for some reason. Try using the `reset` command.